# Nest API: Bug Setting Target High & Low Temp

Tags: nest-api

Using the Firebase library I'm able to set the target temperature for heat and cool modes, but when using the heat-cool mode it throws an error each time I try to set the target high or low temp without an explanation:

```
target_temperature_high_f
target_temperature_low_f

FIREBASE WARNING: set at /devices/thermostats/har1gMAZpj0xiMVUiljAV3otrwi6BTjA/target_temperature_low_f failed: failure
```

The strange part is that if I go into the nest.home.com dashboard it allows me to set the high and low temperature without issue.

Answer (score 3):

I've just done a lot of testing in firebase, trying to reproduce your issue:

hvac_mode = **heat-cool**:

- set target_temperature_high_f = no error
- set target_temperature_low_f = no error
- set target_temperature_f = **error**

hvac_mode = **heat** or hvac_mode = **cool**:

- set target_temperature_high_f = **error**
- set target_temperature_low_f = **error**
- set target_temperature_f = no error

The errors are always like yours: "... failed: failure". However, each error is only thrown if you are trying to set the temperature to a *new* value.

Ensuring that you are in the correct mode will prevent the error.

Comment: This should have been a comment (or comment series), not an answer, since it's about troubleshooting to find the root cause, not fixing that cause itself.

Comment: The "cause" is not being in "heat-cool" mode, therefore checking that you are definitely in "heat-cool" mode is the answer.

Comment: "Can you check that [some diagnosis precondition] when receiving the error you describe?" sounds *exactly* like troubleshooting. Perhaps you can rephrase.